# Find count of elements in a Vector

Tags: actionscript-3

If I assign a Vector like

```
var vec1:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(3);
vec1 = (1,2);
```

the result of `vec1.length` is 3. Is there any built-in method to return the number of the elements actually present in the vector?

I'm an ActionScript noob so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can solve your problem by creating an empty vector instead of a defining the vector size at the time of its declaration and then you gradually add  and remove elements to the vector. In this way you will always get the total number of elements inside the vector when you call `vector.length`
For example:

```
var vec1:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
vec1.push(5);
vec1.push(6,7);
vec1.pop();
```

Then `vec1.length` would give you 2.

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile, heres the reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

I believe the .length is the normal way to check its length. If you want to check for "empty elements" you will need to loop through it with a loop.

I don't remmember the exact syntax, but to loop, do something like:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
    if (vec[i] == ... );
    count++;
}
```